# Simple signal processing in C#

Tags: c#, signal-processing

I'm sampling a real-world sensor, and I need to display its filtered value. The signal is sampled at a rate of 10 Hz and during that period it could rise as much as 80 per cent of the maximum range.

Earlier I've used Root Mean Square as a filter and just applying it to the last five values I've logged. For this application this wouldn't be good because I don't store unchanged values. In other words, I need to consider time in my filter...

I've read at [DSP Guide](http://www.dspguide.com/), but I didn't get much out of it. Is there a tutorial that's pinned specifically at programmers, and not [Mathcad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathcad) engineers? Are there some simple code snippets that could help?

*Update*: After several spreadsheet tests I've taken the executive decision to log all samples, and apply a [Butterworth filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterworth_filter).

Comment: So the problem with computing only last five values is that the they don't reflect the real time since the unchanged data is not logged? Am I understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You always need to store some values (but not necessarily
all input values). A filter's current output depends on a
number of input values and possibly some past output values.

The simplest filter would be a first order Butterworth low-pass
filter. This would only require you to store one past output
value. The (current) output of the filter, y(n) is:

y(n) = x(n) - a1 * y(n-1)

where x(n) is the current input and y(n-1) is the previous
output of the filter. a1 depends on the cut-off frequency
and the sampling frequency. The cut-off frequency frequency
must be less than 5 Hz (half the sampling frequency),
sufficiently low to filter out the noise, but not so low
that the output will be delayed with respect to the input. And of
course not so low that the real signal is filtered out!

In code (mostly C#):

```
double a1 = 0.57; //0.57 is just an example value.
double lastY = 0.0;
while (true)
{
    double x = <get an input value>;

    double y = x - a1 * lastY;

    <Use y somehow>

    lastY = y;
}
```

Whether a first order filter is sufficient depends on your
requirements and the characteristics of the input signal (a
higher order filter may be able to suppress more of the
noise at the expense of higher delay of the output signal).

For higher order filters, more values would have to be stored
and the code becomes a little bit more complicated. Usually
the values need to be shifted down in arrays; in an array
for past y values and in an array for past x values.

Comment: Is it a filter? The result data (y) will be the same as x but a1*lastY less. Nothing is been filtered here.

Answer (score 5):

In DSP, the term "filter" usually refers to the amplification or attenuation (i.e. "lowering") of frequency components within a continuous signal.  This is commonly done using Fast Fourier Transform (FFT).  FFT starts with a signal recorded over a given length of time (the data are in what's called the "time domain") and transforms these values into what's called the "frequency domain", where the results indicate the strength of the signal in a series of frequency "bins" that range from 0 Hz up to the sampling rate (10 Hz in your case).  So, as a rough example, an FFT of one second's worth of your data (10 samples) would tell you the strength of your signal at 0-2 Hz, 2-4 Hz, 4-6 Hz, 6-8 Hz, and 8-10 Hz.

To "filter" these data, you would increase or decrease any or all of these signal strength values, and then perform a reverse FFT to transform these values back into a time-domain signal.  So, for example, let's say you wanted to do a lowpass filter on your transformed data, where the cutoff frequency was 6 Hz (in other words, you want to remove any frequency components in your signal above 6 Hz).  You would programatically set the 6-8 Hz value to zero and set the 8-10 Hz value to 0, and then do a reverse FFT.

I mention all this because it doesn't sound like "filtering" is really what you want to do here.  I think you just want to display the current value of your sensor, but you want to smooth out the results so that it doesn't respond excessively to transient fluctuations in the sensor's measured value.  The best way to do this is with a simple running average, possibly with the more recent values weighted more heavily than older values.

A running average is very easy to program (*much* easier than FFT, trust me) by storing a collection of the most recent measurements.  You mention that your app only stores values that are different from the prior value.  Assuming you also store the time at which each value is recorded, it should be easy for your running average code to fill in the "missing values" by using the recorded prior values.

Comment: You are correct, I do not want to mess with FFT. I don't mind math or anything, but when I see a FFT implementation (or function) I get a cold chill down my back.

Comment: It's actually fun, once you get through the initial pain, and it opens up a lot of doors as far as signal processing goes.

Comment: A running average *is* a filter. It's a simple filter, but a filter nonetheless. "Smoothing out the results" is exactly the same as removing or lowering high frequency components.

Comment: @rorold: agree with your first two sentences but not the third. Smoothing in the time domain affects all frequencies (albeit not equally) and will not produce *exactly* the same results as attenuation of high frequencies in the frequency domain.

Comment: @MusiGenesis Actually, it can produce the same results. Multiplication in the frequency domain (which is what you do when you attenuate frequencies) is exactly the same as convolution in the time domain (i.e. a weighted moving average). To get _exactly_ the same results I guess you would have to take the inverse DFT of the attenuation function and use that as the weights for the moving average, which might be quite a long moving average. But my (admittedly somewhat pedantic) original point was that your answer implied that only frequency domain processing is filtering, which is not the case.

Comment: @rorold: `Multiplication in the frequency domain ... is exactly the same as convolution in the time domain`. This is most definitely not correct. Applying a running average in the time domain affects *all* frequencies in the signal to a greater or lesser extent. It would be accurate to state that frequency manipulation *can* be done so as to  have the same effect on the signal output as a running average, but they do not generally/usually produce the same effects. As one would expect, frequency domain manipulation allows much more precise control over frequency components.

Comment: @MusiGenesis It is, it's [mathematically proven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem). I take your point that a simple running average will not give as precise results as frequency manipulation, but it is still possible, with enough filter coefficients, to implement a time-domain filter that will. Even manipulating in the frequency domain you can't be 100% precise, because the FFT has a limited frequency resolution so when you transform back to the time domain other frequencies will be affected too.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a tutorial that will help you, but in C# you may want to consider using Reactive LINQ - see blog post *[Reactive programming (II.) - Introducing Reactive LINQ](http://tomasp.net/blog/reactive-ii-csevents.aspx)*.

As a way to get the events, so you can do your processing without having to store all the values, it would just do the processing as you get the next event in.

To consider time, you could just use an exponential with a negative exponent to decrease the impact of the past measurements.

Comment: +1 for the link, seems to be a very nice idea.  However, it seems a bit out-of-context for his actual problem...  For me it seems his main problem is that he only stores changes, not signal over time, where for his calculation he would need the latter.  Storing the time or changing the logging itself would probably suffice.

Comment: It seems that he wants to keep one value, but to add time to it the value needs to decrease before adding in the new value. This will reduce older values more, over time, and by using reactive linq he can better have one algorithm that will do what he needs.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, for complex real-time systems sampling multiple streams of data, there could be an issue in the data processing (calculation and storage of data) and data consistency.